# Installed php74-php-mysqlnd but module is not available

Tags: centos, php, mysql, centos-8

I am setting up a clean CentOS 8 server and installed PHP using the Remi repositories. In there, it also has a `php74-php-mysqlnd` package that should be installing the correct `.so` files, but I do not see them in the `/usr/lib64/php/modules` dir. `php -m` doens't show any MySQL modules either.

How can I install `mysqli_*` support in PHP7.4 on CentOS 8?

Comment: You may have installed the extension, but did you enable it? Check `php.ini` and its included files.

Comment: @DanielB I found the extension files in `/opt/remi/php74`, but fail to get how to correctly use this in my setup. I was in the understanding that `dnf` would help me there as well...

Comment: You probably need php-mysqlnd...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I still had the default `php-fpm` running.

I removed that and installed `php74-php-fpm`, and restarted apache.

I got it working now.

Comment: You miss the wizard instructions https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/
And you miss the FAQ about  php-* vs php74-php-* https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#scl